# send a cypher using the url from th browser?

Tags: neo4j

How can I send (programatically) a cypher query to neo4j browser (via get/post) in order to display the resulted graph? e.g., something like: http://localhost:7474/browser/query='match n return n'

Comment: The Cypher end point requires a POST - I suspect due to GET string limit in URL. Anyway I think you can just build your own proxy endpoint and forward the query via POST.